# format date using jquery and codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Just want to display formatted date using Jquery and Codeigniter.

I get date from db in the following format: 2014-09-06

Want to display: 6 Sep 2014

Is there any function which can help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better make a helper function and call within view. The function can be like this -

```
function format_date($date=""){
  return date("j F Y",strtotime($date));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. Do you know which type I should use for mysql table cell in order to insert date in it in the following format **6 Sep 2014** ?

Comment: you can only insert YYYY-MM-DD format in MySQL date field.

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to make the convertion using jquery, try this:

```
getMonthName = function (v) {
var n = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
return n[v]
}
var da =new Date("2014-09-06"); // Give your date here
alert(da.getDate() + " " + getMonthName(da.getMonth()) + " " + (da.getYear()+1900));
// This results: 6 Sep 2014
```

Check on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afghanWiz/ts3t71fa/2/)